# Forget password mobile otp authentication android firebase

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, forgot-password, one-time-password

User can sign up with mobile no in firebase. Once he logged out and forget his password how user can get reset his account

Answer (score 0):

You can sign the user in to the same account by [sending them a new verification code/OTP](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone) to the same number as before.